# S3: Only allow files with certain pattern

Tags: regex, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I'm not sure if this is feasible. I'm looking for a way to limit the files that can be saved into an S3 bucket to a certain pattern (number.*, e.g. 2893.jpg or 18928.png). Can this be done thru IAM policy or is there another way?

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell us more about your situation? Who or what is doing the uploading? Is it from a mobile app, or via a web app, or is it using IAM credentials and direct API calls? Feel free to Edit your question to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native way to do this. Permissions can be assigned to upload to a particular Prefix (folder), but there is no method for specifying permitted characters in a Key (filename).

You would likely want to **implement a frontend that verifies filenames** and allows upload via a pre-signed URL.

See: [Uploading Objects Using Presigned URLs - Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html)